# How can I relink an item in a form library using JSOM?

Tags: infopath, jsom, form-library

I am looking for a way to relink items in a form library using client-side JavaScript.

I've found [this forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fc5c58f4-d125-4bb9-b953-1a042d034b03/how-to-programmatically-relink-infopath-form-template-with-the-correct-zone?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy) on MSDN which has some PowerShell and C# code, but how can I do the same thing using JSOM?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the C# example on the link above, you can relink a document by setting its `TemplateUrl` field to the desired URI and saving the changes.

Here is a simple example of how you could do this for a single document, given a specific ID:

```
const listTitle = 'MyLibraryName';
const itemId = 12345;
const contentTypeUri = 'https://mysite.sharepoint.com/Library/Forms/template.xsn';

const context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
const list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
const item = list.getItemById(itemId);

item.set_item('TemplateUrl', contentTypeUri);
item.update();

context.executeQueryAsync(
    () => console.log('done'), 
    (_, e) => console.error(e.get_message())
);
```